# React Native Maps Custom Marker blocking Marker onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have custom markers being rendered to my map and do so exactly as I want.  I'm using Custom Marker which is a View, Image, and then text specific to an event over the image.

For some reason using a custom marker view is blocking the onPress on the Marker component.

I've tested the onPress event as similiar to below for testing:

`<Marker onPress={() => {console.log('Pressed')}}> ...` but only logs the press message when I remove my custom marker view inside the Marker component.

Is there a reason why the custom marker view would be stopping the onPress?  How do I get around this and fire an onPress event for a custom marker?

Added full code below for better look. Right now it is working but only because I am using the `onSelect` event for iOS.  The `onPress` works the way it is for Android but not iOS.

```
<MapView 
    style={styles.map} 
    ref={ map => {this.map = map }}
    region={this.state.region}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    loadingEnabled={true}
>
    {matches.map((marker, index) => {
            return (
                <MapMarker 
                    key={index}
                    mapMarker={marker}
                    handlePress={() => {
                        this.map.animateToRegion({
                            latitude: marker.location.latlng.latitude,
                            longitude: marker.location.latlng.longitude
                        }, 100)
                    }}
                />
            )
    })} 
</MapView>
```

`MapMarker.js`

```
render() {
        const { mapMarker } = this.props;

        return (
            <Marker
                ref={(ref) => {this.markerRef = ref; }}
                coordinate={mapMarker.location.latlng}
                title={mapMarker.location.streetName}
                stopPropagation={true}
                pointerEvents='auto'
                onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
                onSelect={() => {
                    this.props.handlePress();
                }}
            >

                <CustomMapMarker 
                    gameType={mapMarker.matchType} 
                    isSanctioned={mapMarker.isSanctioned}
                    startDate={mapMarker.startAt}
                />

                <Callout style={styles.customCallout}>
                    <CustomMarkerCallout markerInfo={mapMarker} /> 
                </Callout>
            </Marker>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code on how to use your custom marker into the Marker class?

Comment: @Kuray-FreakyCoder- added the code.  Also got it working using the `onSelect` for iOS and the `onPress` works for Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding `onSelect` which is iOS specific.  The `onPress` was only working for Android so don't know if this is the right answer but is working for me as of now.